# Angular Ui's ui-grid not aligning properly

Tags: angularjs

[image]

I have a series of ui-grid's contained within an ui-accordion.

My problem is that (as you can see in the picture) the ui-grid contents don't align with the ui-grid columns (SOMETIMES). You can see that the first 2 align perfectly, while the third one is oddly compressed.

I'm not sure what's causing this. When you refresh the page, sometimes all 3 ui-grids are perfectly aligned. Other times, all three will be squished.

I'd appreciate any help!
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the code ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm seeing the same issue.